# What type of USB cable is used for the Panasonic TZ40?

Tags: panasonic, usb, panasonic-lumix, charger

I have appeared to have lost the original USB charging cable for my TZ40. At my best guess, I went to 2 computer shops today to try a 8 pin mini USB. It fitted, but neither charged it...

I just grabbed my dad's FujiFilm cable, which (luckily) has the same charging port, and works. But it does not appear to have 8 pins, To describe it, it has 1 pin then a gap followed by 4 pins. What is this cable called? 5 pin mini USB? Though searching through Google Images, it's not that?

Edit:

UC-E6 connector ?

Here's the working cable:
[image]

Comment: I've seen it referred to as "8-Pin" e.g. https://pinoutguide.com/DigitalCameras/micro_usb_8pin_camera_pinout.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is not a standard USB connection. It is a non-USB UC-E6 connection used by a few digital camera manufacturers such as Sony and Nikon.

More information can be found here:

- [Which devices use UC-E6 plug](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85788/which-devices-use-uc-e6-plug)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Connector_types
- http://connector.pinoutsguide.com/8_pin_UC-E6_like-mini-usb_proprietary/

Comment: Why did they do this?

Comment: @vy32 I don't work at Panasonic so I can only speculate. Typically non-standard USB connections are used for technical or marketing reasons. For example, UC-E6 is very small and compact even when compared to USB mini or micro. Another example would be the Apple Lightning connection chosen for multiple functionality and marketing purposes.