# Is the Panasonic data connector a standard USB Mini-B

Tags: file-transfer, usb

My Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GM5 comes with an unusual data connector for transferring photos to the computer. The manual identifies the part as USB connection Cable DMW-USBC1. When I look that up, the [official Panasonic page](https://shop.panasonic.com/cameras-and-camcorders/camera-and-camcorder-accessories/camcorder-accessories/camcorder-replacement-accessories/DMW-USBC1.html) doesn't provide any additional information about the connector.

Through research, it looks very similar to a USB Mini-B connector. For example:

- This [related question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62363/what-type-of-usb-cable-is-used-for-the-panasonic-tz40) indicates it's the same as "UC-E6"
- A site called Pinout Guide says "[This plug used in many digital cameras. Often called 8 pin mini-usb, but not standard](https://pinoutguide.com/DigitalCameras/micro_usb_8pin_camera_pinout.shtml)" and indicates that UC-E6 is the same or related
- [Monoprice sells a cable](https://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=2735) that indicates it will be compatible and says USB Mini-B
- This [Belkin Mini-B cable on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WJSPWUO) has a number of reviews that say they are using it to connect to cameras.

If it's the same connector (i.e. USB Mini-B) with the same pins then that will make it easy to replace it or get a new one that connects to USB-C.

Update: I don't have a good macro so here are the best images I can get of the connectors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Macro photographs of the cable connector and receptacle that clearly show the pins would be helpful. (Count the pins. Go to a store, and ask to try some cables.)

Comment: Have you asked Panasonic?

Comment: @mattdm While in general a good idea, I would bet quite a bit of money that their answer would include some corp-speak like "Panasonic is determined to deliver the best user experience. As such, we cannot comment on whether or not third party cables work on our camera. Third party equipment might damage your equipment, in which case your warranty is void." That's the answer I always got from manufacturers (though I never had contact eith Pana)

Answer (score 3):

It's the same cable as for my DMC-FZ200 and a whole wagonload of older and newer Panasonic models.  Quite a number of third-party sources for cheap variants.  It's definitely not compatible with any standard USB connector and may have been around before micro-USB was standardized.  Also the socket contains pins for video I think.  Here are photographs of socket (the right one in the photograph is USB/AV, the left being HDMI) and plug:[image: HDMI and USB/AV sockets of Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ200]
[image: Panasonic USB plug]
So bite the bullet and get one.  They are comparatively cheap and ubiquitous.  Usually it's more convenient to just swap the SDcard though.  With the FZ200, the corresponding flap is so close to the tripod mount that you cannot do so without unmounting the camera.  The solution I finally adapted was using a lens clamp for holding the camera on the tripod.  That way, the SDcard flap stays accessible.  It may well be that the GM5 does not have a similarly absurd SDcard
access position but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Amazon and enter "Lumix DMC-GM5 USB". You will see what they sell for that, which is a pin-out known as UC-E6.

However... this is a USB-2 cable, which means your photo transfers will only go at USB-2 speeds. With a USB-3 card reader, you can read the SD cards as SD cards speeds which is about twice as fast.

Comment: Unfortunately my new Macbook Pro lacks an SD card reader. USB C only.

Comment: There are USB-C card readers.

Answer (score 0):

The cable is --- non-USB UC-E6

Comment: What are the differences? Are they physical, electrical or both?